# How to use an AutoCompleteExtender from within a user control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, autocompleteextender

I have created a user control, in which I plan to use every time the user edits certain content and a regular ASPX page where I call the user control. The user cotrol contains a few textbox and an AutoCompleteExtender. Everything works fine except the Extender. I've used it in many other APSX pages and worked like a charm, but for some reason it doesn't seem to work here. After debugging, through chrome, I found out that I don't have access to the method(405). After a few days of scavenging, the internet, I found this:

> "A callable page method is a public static (or Shared in Visual Basic®
>   .NET) method defined in the codebehind class and decorated with the
>   same WebMethod attribute used for Web service methods. At present,
>   this is limited to ASPX pages-both inline and codebehind code-but
>   might be extended in the future to **user controls** and custom controls."

Also, stumbled upon other forums suggesting a web service instead of a web method. Tried this and still got the same (405) error. I've being stuck for almost a week and I've ran out of options. Is this a bad practice and that's why you can't do it? All I want is to keep it all on the same user control and aspx.

This is how I'm using the extender on my user control:

```
<aspx:AutoCompleteExtender ID="tbEntitiesAutoCompleteEx" runat="server"
      BehaviorID="tbEntitiesAutoCompleteEx" TargetControlID="tbEntity"
      UseContextKey="True" ServiceMethod="GetAutocompleteEntities"
      MinimumPrefixLength="3" CompletionSetCount="10" CompletionInterval="300"
      CompletionListCssClass="autoCompleteList"
      CompletionListItemCssClass="autoCompleteItem" 
      CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="autoCompleteHighlightedItem"       
      CompletionListElementID="divCodeAutoCompletePlacement"  
      OnClientPopulating="OnEntitiesPopulating" 
      OnClientPopulated="OnEntitiesPopulated" 
      OnClientItemSelected="OnEntitySelected"                                
      ShowOnlyCurrentWordInCompletionListItem="true" 
      FirstRowSelected="true" ServicePath ="~/InterventionsWebService.asmx" />
```

I've changed the service path to `~/InterventionsWebService.asmx`(web service in the same directory),  `CreateEdit.aspx`(page I call user control) and `CreateEdit.ascx`(user control it's self) and none worked.

This is the web Method:

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public List<string> GetAutocompleteEntities(string prefixText, int count, string contextKey)
{
    var bbq = 0

    return new List<string>();
}
```

I've also tried making it into a static method but still not working.
I have a break point on `var bbq = 0` but it never hits due to the (405) error.
Any explanation would be nice, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix my problem. I removed the service path, placed the web method in the aspx where the ascx is being called, made the web method static and managed to hit the break point.

Answer (score 0):

I put the WebMethod on the webpage and used it to call a method on the UserControl.